# Exact definition of weak convergence of empirical processes

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

Consider the i.i.d. random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ with $X_i:\Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ $\forall i$ and probability distribution $P$.

Consider a class $\mathcal{F}$ of functions $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Define the empirical process $G_n:=\{\sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(X_i)-\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(x)dP(x)) \text{ s.t. } f\in \mathcal{F}\}$.

A sample path for a fixed $\omega \in \Omega$ is a map $f\in \mathcal{F}\mapsto \sqrt{n}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(X_i(\omega))-\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(x)dP(x))\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of all sample paths.

$G_n$ can be also seen as a random map $ \Omega\rightarrow\mathcal{A}$.

Let $l^{\infty}(\mathcal{F})$ be the set of functions $z:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}}|z(f)|<\infty$.

Suppose I'm told that $G_n$ weakly converges to a stochastic process $G_p$ **"in $l^\infty(\mathcal{F})$"** (e.g. [here](https://www.stat.washington.edu/jaw/RESEARCH/TALKS/Delft/emp-proc-delft-big.pdf) at the top of page 3). **What's the exact definition of weak convergence of the empirical process?**

**My attempt**: $G_n$ converges in distribution to a stochastic process $G_p$ in $l^\infty(\mathcal{F})$ means that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E^*_{X_1,...,X_n}h(G_n)=E_{X_1,...,X_n}h(G_p)$ $\forall$ functions $h: l^{\infty}(\mathcal{F})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and bounded.

But, if this interpretation is correct, do we need $l^{\infty}(\mathcal{F}) \in \mathcal{A}$? And, similarly, if $G_p$ is a map from $\Omega$  $\mathcal{B}$ do we need $l^{\infty}(\mathcal{F}) \in \mathcal{B}$?

Comment: The theme here seems to be "Let's make the central limit theorem as difficult to understand as possible."

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having issues in understanding the specific role of each object. I know the central limit theorem for random vectors but when it comes to stochastic processes I get confused.

Comment: While I could not understand your descriptions (on what $\mathcal{F}$ is, or why $G_n$ seems to be defined in terms of itself), it may help to note that the central limit theorem for iid random variables with finite variance says $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-E[X])$ converges in distribution to a Gaussian with mean 0 and variance $Var(X)$, but not convergence in probability or with probability 1.

Comment: I'm using the notation in van der Vaart "Asymptotic Statistics"

Comment: I see your edit that clarifies what $\mathcal{F}$ means.  I am still having trouble with $G_n$.

Comment: I have edited again. Does it make more sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36483/discussion-between-michael-and-stf).

Comment: I wanted to try providing more help than just notational clarification:  I found notes by Googling "central limit theorem for random vectors."  This is the first link I found, perhaps these notes are more readable than the ones you have:  http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~dhunter/asymp/lectures/chpt04.pdf

Comment: Theorem 4.9 of the notes I linked to seems to state what you would want:  The central limit theorem indeed applies to random vectors, and the result is that the appropriately scaled summation converges (in distribution) to a jointly Gaussian vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is not quite right. See the discussion at the top of page 5 of your (Wellner) reference.
Weak convergence in $\ell^\infty(\cal F)$ means
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} E^*h(G_n)= Eh(G_p)
$$ 
for all continuous bounded $h$ that map $\ell^\infty(\cal F)$ to $\mathbb R$. The expectation on the LHS is indeed with respect to the joint distribution of $X_1\ldots X_n$, since that's all that $G_n$ is based on. But the rhs cannot depend on $n$.

As for the connection between $\cal A$ and $l^\infty(F)$, typically we expect the sample paths for $G_n$ and $G_p$ to be bounded almost surely, which means we can assume $\cal A$ and $\cal B$ are both subsets of $l^\infty(F)$. If you stare at the definitions you'll realize that a statement like $l^{\infty}(\mathcal{F}) \in \mathcal{A}$ can't be right.